# Why is my total not coming up correctly, and how can I fix it?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, reporting-services

I'm working on remaking an Access report in SSRS with data from a SQL Server.
In the report I have a matrix, and one of the values is SumOfPieces. 
SumOfPieces is in my Query as `sum(t1.pieces) as SumOfPieces`.
Inside the table I get the correct row values by just using [SumOfPieces], but my total is not adding anything together. For example this is what I am getting:

```
Product | Facility | Shift/Line | Pieces
BFS     | BRWP     | A 1        | 65,000
BFS     | MHWP     | A 2        | 70,000
BFS     | MHWP     | B 2        | 80,000
________________________________________
Total   |          |            | 70,000
```

For some reason it's giving me the middle value
The expression for the total is simply `=Sum(fields!SumOfPieces.Value)`
I tried different variations of something like this expression `=Sum(avg(fields!SumPieces.Value,"Product1")`

In Access this is accomplished with queries nested 4-5 deep. 
For this field specifically it looks like

- Original query t1 with t1.Pieces
- Next query on t1 with t1.Pieces summed as t1.SumOfPieces
- Next query joins t1 with others

The Access report just uses that SumOfPieces as the row value, and then a sum(SumOfPieces) for the total.

Sample of my Dataset Query:

```
SELECT
   StaveHistorySummary.fk_Inspectors
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_InspectionSites
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductionLines
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductTypes
  ,StaveHistorySummary.DateMade
  ,StaveHistorySummary.[TimeStamp]
  ,StaveHistorySummary.StaveHistoryguid
  ,InspectionSites.SiteAbbr
  ,Inspectors.Name
  ,ProductTypes.Product
  ,ProductionLines.LineName
  ,CAST(sum(Millproduction.Pieces) as int) AS SumPieces
  ,CASE 
     WHEN SapEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN SapEdgingInches
     WHEN HeartEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN HeartEdgingInches
     WHEN BothEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN BothEdgingInches
     WHEN SawnIncorrInches IS NOT NULL THEN SawnIncorrInches
     WHEN EqualizedIncorrInches IS NOT NULL THEN EqualizedIncorrInches
     WHEN SawnOKInches IS NOT NULL THEN SawnOKInches
     END AS WIDTH
FROM
  StaveHistorySummary
  INNER JOIN ProductionLines
    ON StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductionLines = ProductionLines.ProductionLines_NDX
  INNER JOIN InspectionSites
    ON StaveHistorySummary.fk_InspectionSites = InspectionSites.InspectionSites_NDX
  INNER JOIN ProductTypes
    ON StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductTypes = ProductTypes.ProductTypes_NDX
  INNER JOIN Inspectors
    ON StaveHistorySummary.fk_Inspectors = Inspectors.Inspectors_NDX
  INNER JOIN MillProduction
    ON inspectionsites.inspectionsites_ndx = MillProduction.fk_inspectionsites
      AND productionlines.productionlines_ndx = MillProduction.fk_productionlines
      AND producttypes.producttypes_ndx = millproduction.fk_producttypes
WHERE (CAST(CAST(stavehistorysummary.DateMade as date) as datetime) BETWEEN '6/16/2019' AND '6/22/2019')
AND (CAST(CAST(MillProduction.DateMade as date) as datetime) BETWEEN '6/16/2019' AND '6/22/2019')
GROUP BY 
StaveHistorySummary.fk_Inspectors
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_InspectionSites
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductionLines
  ,StaveHistorySummary.fk_ProductTypes
  ,StaveHistorySummary.DateMade
  ,StaveHistorySummary.[TimeStamp]
  ,StaveHistorySummary.StaveHistoryguid
  ,InspectionSites.SiteAbbr
  ,Inspectors.Name
  ,ProductTypes.Product
  ,ProductionLines.LineName
  ,CAST(sum(Millproduction.Pieces) as int) AS SumPieces
  ,CASE 
     WHEN SapEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN SapEdgingInches
     WHEN HeartEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN HeartEdgingInches
     WHEN BothEdgingInches IS NOT NULL THEN BothEdgingInches
     WHEN SawnIncorrInches IS NOT NULL THEN SawnIncorrInches
     WHEN EqualizedIncorrInches IS NOT NULL THEN EqualizedIncorrInches
     WHEN SawnOKInches IS NOT NULL THEN SawnOKInches
     END AS WIDTH
```

[image: Image of Matrix]

Comment: The fact that you are referencing the dataset in your total implies it's outside of a dataset. Why are you not using groupings here?

Comment: What is the data type of the columns are you sure there int/numbers and not strings

Comment: @Larnu are you talking about ```=Sum(Avg(fields!SumOfPieces.Value, "Product1")```? My understanding is that the "Product1" is referencing my row group which is called "Product1".

Comment: @Brad I checked them and they were set as "default" I changed them to Numbers, but I am still left with the same result.

Comment: Using the `avg` function will definitely not get the right result, but `=Sum(Fields!SumOfPieces.Value, "Product1")` should.  Could you provide more of the query that is being used for this?

Comment: @Steve-o169 I did try not having the avg and doing exactly what you suggested, but still no change to the result. avg definitely did not give me the desired result, you are right there. I just put portion of my query into my post.

Comment: A pic of your **design view** may help figuring what the issue is. Be sure to have a cell in the table selected so you can see the grouping lines on the left of the tablix. You should have an outer grouping line `(` like a left parenthesis that covers your detail lines and your total line. Your detail could have another grouping line `(` if you need to sum multiple shit/lines or have three lines `=` like a hamburger menu to indicated detail rows.

Comment: @HannoverFist I've added an image of my Matrix in SSRS

Comment: Your grouping looks correct. If you have multiple records for Products, Sites, or Line, your Pieces expression should be `=Sum(Fields!SumOfPieces.Value)` but that doesn't fix your grand TOTAL problem though.

Comment: Is the dataset called "Product1"?  Or is that the outermost group?  Another option if those `SumPieces` fields are static would be to just give unique names to those textboxes and just call them directly.  `=(ReportItems!LineSum.Value + ReportItems!SiteSum.Value + ReportItems!ProductSum.Value)`  Not the most elegant solution but might work for your purposes.